# MariaDB, Triggers and last_insert_id

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb, auto-increment

I have a situation where I have three tables: sample, sample_name and run (extra columns removed to be only relevant information).

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `sample_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sample_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `sample_name` (
  `sample_name_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `project` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sample_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sample_name_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY `fk_sample` (`sample_id`) REFERENCES `sample` (`sample_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE KEY `un_sample_name` (`name`,`project`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `run` (
  `run_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sample_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`run_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY `fk_run1` (`sample_id`) REFERENCES `sample` (`sample_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I would like to check if a sample (based on sample_name) exists or if not, then insert both and use the sample_id to insert run entry as well. To do this I planned first to check if the unique name (name + project) exists and if so use it. However if it doesn't, then use trigger to do double insertion (I have a perl script to do this logic; I tried also the commented update version).

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER tr_new_sample BEFORE INSERT ON sample_name FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.sample_id IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO sample () VALUES ();
    -- UPDATE sample_name SET NEW.sample_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET NEW.sample_id := (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
  END IF;
END |
delimiter ;
```

So when sample name does not exists, I try to insert a record with null sample_id and thus the trigger reacts. However this doesn't work and I get a following error. Can someone suggest on how to fix this or make it work.

The database is actually MariaDB 5.2.12.

Thanks,

```
mysql> INSERT INTO sample_name (name,project) VALUES ('a','a_project');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pipeline_runs`.`sample_name`, CONSTRAINT `sample_name_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sample_id`) REFERENCES `sample` (`sample_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I try to insert a record with null sample_id

```
`sample_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
```

The sample_id can't be null.  You will probably find NEW.sample_id = 0 inside the trigger if you don't specify a value on insert, since you have declared the column as `NOT NULL`... so you need to test for that instead:

```
IF NEW.sample_id = 0 THEN
...
```

...or change your table definition to allow null values.

---

**Update** (for the benefit of future visitors):

MySQL [Bug #6295](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6295) (yes, from 9 years ago) is resolved in MySQL 5.7.1 and apparently changes this behavior so that `NOT NULL` validation is not imposed until *after* the `BEFORE` trigger is processed.  This behavior will likely make its way into MariaDB at some point also.  If the original poster of this question is using the `= 0` test that currently works, it's possible that this behavior change could cause that logic to fail since the timing (or occurrence, at all) of the coercion to from `NULL` to 0 might also change.

> If a column is declared as `NOT NULL`, it is not permitted to insert `NULL` into the column or update it to `NULL`. However, this constraint was enforced even if there was a `BEFORE INSERT` (or `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger) that set the column to a non-`NULL` value. Now the constraint is checked at the end of the statement, per the SQL standard. (Bug #6295, Bug #11744964)
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-1.html</sup>

*See also:* http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6030

Comment: That works, thank you. Went with the '= 0' version. I was thinking that since the trigger is meant to go off before insert, it would have been done before NOT NULL constraint is checked. But it seems not.